# Laravel blade simple inline if statement

Tags: php, laravel

Is it possible with Laravel Blade templating to write a statement like this?

If alt image field exists in database, add. If not, leave out.  What is happening with the code below is the double quotes alt="text" get rendered.

```
<img src="#" {{$product->extra_img1_alt ? 'alt="'. $product->extra_img1_alt .'"' : ''}}>
```

Comment: It's best to leave logic like this in the controller and not have it in the template. Whynot just move the ternary to the controller and just output the variable?

Comment: @Kevinhowbrook I'd do it in the view in this particular case. Would be kinda weird to have `$product->alt` be some sort of weird drop-in HTML attribute/value pair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text in `{{` tags are escaped automatically, so you need something more like this:

```
<img src="#"
     @if($product->extra_img1_alt)
         alt="{{ $product->extra_img1_alt }}"
     @endif
>
```

That said, while you seem to be trying to avoid it, there's nothing really wrong with an empty `alt` attribute:

```
<img src="#" alt="{{ $product->extra_img1_alt }}">
```

Comment: ok thanks.  I was wondering if there was a simpler way.  And thanks, I wasn't aware a blank alt tag was ok.

Comment: @user1040259 You could also use `{!!`, which won't escape, but that makes you vulnerable to XSS if `$product->extra_img1_alt` contains user-submitted data, or breakage if you accidentally put a `"` in the alt text.

Answer (score 3):

My dear friend, you just need to change the code

```
<img src="#" alt=" @if($product->extra_img1_alt) {{$product->extra_img1_alt}} @endif ">
```

Comment: This will produce an empty `alt=""` if it's missing, which OP seems to want.